# OrientDB - Studio, creating a new record with a binary data attribute

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, binary-data

Fellow OrientDB users,

I'm fairly new to OrientDB and have run into an issue! Please help! :)

**Problem:**
I've added an attribute to a vertex. The data type for this attribute is binary. As I attempt to create a new record, I choose a small image to upload to the binary field for this record. When I click "Save", I get this error:

{"errors":[{"code":500,"reason":500,"content":"com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Error on unmarshalling JSON content for record: \"@class\":\"Photo\",\"@version\":0,\"@rid\":\"#-1:-1\",\"image\":null,\"firstname\":\"Jimmy\",\"grade_level\":13,\"school_id\":1,\"id\":24000,\"reference_no\":4,\"lastname\":\"Dean\",\"{{ header }}\":\"$file\"\r\n--> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid field name '{{ header }}'. Character ' ' is invalid"}]}

I know that there is a way to do this via RESTful API but I'm curious if its possible via the Studio. This capability would be very helpful in just getting some fake data in the DB real quick so I can build out some other features as a proof of concept to make sure I'm on the right path.

[Here is a snapshot of where and when I get the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeT5N.png)

Also, I was looking at this thread: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2336

In a comment from over a year ago, it said studio wasn't supporting it, but I'm not sure if there have been any updates to that situation.

Thanks all! Let me know if there is any other advice you would give in this situation....ie, other ways of doing what attempting to accomplish, etc.

Comment: HI, what version are you using? Thx